# Managing user permissions in keycloak and spring rest api

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, keycloak, openid-connect

> **TL;DR**
>
> - Objective: managing api permissions:
>
>   - OIDC authorization direct grant flow
>   - User federation and authentication source : LDAP
>   - Permissions store : legacy database
>   - Client management and authentication: Keycloak
> - Question: **What are the best practices for managing user permissions on Keycloak and rest api?**

**Context**

We are implementing a rest API with spring to be used by a mobile application and an SPA. Our users accounts, permissions, rules… and all data are stored in a custom database used by different monolithic applications. To secure our api we have decided to use Keycloak.

The keycloak server is configured with an existing LDAP for user federation and ‘Direct grand flow’ for the mobile client application. For the first use case (authentication) everything is working fine.

Now we have to manage users permissions as follow :

- The client applications should know user permissions to display/hide functionalities
- The api should be able to validate user permissions to use different endpoints
- Users permissions are based on some rules in the database and change frequently

In my understanding keycloak can handle authorization and fine grained permissions using hardcoded or user based policies but can’t be plugged to a different authorization source natively. As a consequence, I thought of building a custom role mapper using **Keycloak SPI**, retrieve user permissions from a custom api that I will develop, then map them to the access token.

As a result, my access token should look like:

```
"resource_access": {
    “My-client”: {
      “permissions”: [
        “Show-products”,
        “Buy-something”,
        “Display-prices”
      ]
    }
  },
  "username": “myUser”
```

Then the mobile application should be able to know user permissions based on the token, and my stateless server side (API) should be able to access user permissions on every call to check them using spring annotation :

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('Show-products')")
```

**Problem**

After first experimenting my solution seem to work fine, but I still have some security concerns about this choice since it’s out of the keycloak standard and includes rest calls to a different backend inside keycloak mappers.

So I was wondering :

- Is it secure to put user permissions on the access token claims?
- How to secure keycloak access to an external system (rest calls) to
  retrieve permissions?
- Should I rely on token claims to verify user permissions on each
  request in my resource server?
- Is there any other clean solution / best practices to handle user
  permissions from external source in keycloak ?

**Complimentary Informations**

I’m using :

- Springboot 1.5.13.RELEASE
- Keycloak-adapter-bom 3.4.3.Final
- Standalone keycloak server 3.4.3.Final

Comment: Hi @wadi3 , did you implement this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regarding your questions:

***- Is it secure to put user permissions on the access token claims?***

Yes, capabilities can (and should be) on the access-token, and with that you can take some decisions in your business layer (based on the roles/access claims). Remember nevertheless that a token is only base 64 encoded, and could be copied by other person and looked into, so it shouldn't contain secret or particularly confidential information, usually you put there enough info regarding the user, and some of its current permissions/capabilities/claims.

***How to secure keycloak access to an external system (rest calls) to retrieve permissions?***

It depends if it needs to be accessed from outside your network. If not, you can leave it unprotected (and unavailbale from outside/or only available for some specific IPs). If it is going to be available from outside/or you want to protect it with keycloack anyway, you can have either a "confidential" or a "bearer only" type of client. I'd suggest you to look into CORS and token sharing, so that you can reuse your already created "access-token" for your other endpoints without the need to authenticate again.

***Should I rely on token claims to verify user permissions on each request in my resource server?***

Not exactly sure what you mean. In keycloak the resource server isn't doing extra resource authorization like in a typical oAuth2 dance (unless your policy enforcer is activated but I believe you didn't go with this approach, but rather a mapper SPI @auth server for getting your roles right?)

In oAuth2 the "resource server" has 2 responsibilities: 1-providing the resource and 2-doing an extra authorization step. In the keycloak world those 2 steps are done by different actors. Step 1 is done by your application, and step2 is only done when policy enforcing is activated by keycloak also (that means Keycloak is the auth server and also part of the "resource server" from the oAuth2 perspective)

Now back to your question, if by resource server you just meant your application providing the content, then yes you can use the claims there, remember that the claims (and the whole access-token) was generated and digitaly-signed by the auth server, so you can use those claims in your app with no problem (and wouldn't know how to do it otherwise either).

**Is there any other clean solution / best practices to handle user permissions from external source in keycloak ?**

Hard to say, as you probably noticed; documentation in the web for your specific usecase is very limited; so not a lot of work of best  practices exist there, you only real alternative would have been using policies with a custom Policy SPI, and that would have brought in other challenges. I'd say your solution is fine.

Best regards.

Comment: Can you maybe give precision on the difference the is between capabilities, claims and permissions ? AFAIK permissions are something very specific in Keycloak and they seem to require an [authorization request](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_service_obtaining_permissions). I'm unsure however of where one should put the limit between a capability (global scope ?) and a permission thus me wanting some clarification on that point.